# Initialize array dynamically in struct

Tags: c

How can I initialize array dynamically in struct Course? I need to make array of student structs.

```
typedef struct {
  char *name; 
   char ID[9];

  } Student;

typedef struct {
  Student *students =  //here
} Course;
```

Comment: you cannot. either allocate in your code, or use a fixed value

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre misread the code, so comment removed. Initializing in just the **declaration** doesn't make sense...

Comment: @FelixPalmen in c++11 this works. but c isn't c++ :)

Comment: ok, let's add something helpful: Please explain what you are trying to achieve with that code. If something isn't working like you expect, please include a [mcve].

Comment: You cannot do it inside the `struct`  definition . Should do it from outside. You may Use `Student **students;` and allocate outside .

Comment: note that you have the same "issue" here: `char *name;`

Comment: Are you sure you wanted dynamical allocation? If this is a homework assignment, perhaps you were just supposed to write `Student students[100]` (like you did with `char ID[9]`)?

Answer (score 2):

Initializing in a `struct` declaration isn't possible, and it wouldn't make sense in C -- you don't have an object of that struct yet.

Assuming you need a variable amount of `Student`s in your array, there are different ways to model that. A typical approach could look like:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t count;
    Student **students;
} Course;
```

With the double-pointer, this is designed to hold "references" to the Student objects (instead of the Student objects themselves). I have to **guess** this is what you need. You could allocate and manage that for example like this:

```
#define CHUNKSIZE 16  // reserve space for this many Students at once

Course *Course_create(void)
{
    Course *course = malloc(sizeof *course);
    if (!course) return 0;

    course->capacity = CHUNKSIZE;
    course->count = 0;
    course->students = malloc(CHUNKSIZE * sizeof *(course->students));
    if (!course->students)
    {
        free(course);
        return 0;
    }

    return course;
}

int Course_addStudent(Course *course, const Student *student)
{
    if (course->count == course->capacity)
    {
        // allocate more memory if needed
        size_t newcapa = course->capacity + CHUNKSIZE;
        Student **newstudents = realloc(course->students, newcapa * sizeof *newstudents);
        if (!newstudents) return 0; // error
        course->capacity = newcapa;
        course->students = newstudents;
    }
    course->students[course->count++] = student;
    return 1; // success
}
```

A proper cleanup could look like this:

```
void Course_destroy(Course *course)
{
    if (!course) return;
    free(course->students);
    free(course);
}
```

Comment: `Student **students;` ? it should be `Student *students;` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre see the paragraph explaining that. Unfortunately, it's unclear what OP needs, but as I assume a `Student` can be member of different `Course`s, that's probably the way to go.

Comment: ah ok, in that case. deallocating this mess properly will be a nightmare, though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if I have such nested structures, I write deallocation functions for each type, using the same semantics as `free()` -- added a simple example. This helps a lot managing it (it kind of resembles a destructor in an OOP language)

Answer (score 0):

`Student *students` is just a pointer to `Student`. You cannot and should not initialize the pointer.

**Method1**

You need to first allocate memory for the struct and then initialize it.

```
// in main 
Course courses;
courses.students = malloc(sizeof(Student));
if (courses.students != NULL_PTR)
{
    courses.students.name = malloc(100);  // 100 would be the size of the name you want to store
    if (courses.students.name != NULL_PTR)
    {
        courses.students.name = "Default Name";
        courses.students.ID = 12345;
    }
}
```

**Method2**

This method removes the pointers from the structs in the first place. It changes the definition of the structure.

Since there are no pointers involved, you can safely inialize the structure on definition.

```
typedef struct {
  char name[100]; 
   char ID[9];

  } Student;

typedef struct {
  Student students;
} Course;


int main(void)
{
    Course courses = {{"Default Name",12345}};

    // other code here
}
```